# How to trick postgres query planner?

Tags: postgresql

I have a following function:

```
create or replace function fast_companies(
  target_size int4range, 
  target_turnover int4range, 
  target_markets integer[], 
  target_countries integer[]
)
returns setof record as $$
begin
    return query
    select c.id
    from companies c
    left join addresses a on c.address_id = a.id
    where
      c.company_size && target_size
      and c.turnover && target_turnover
      -- following two conditions are important
      and (target_markets is null or exists(select * from company_markets cm where cm.company_id = c.id and cm.market_id = any(target_markets)))
      and (target_countries is null or a.country_id = any(target_countries));

end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I takes target_markets and target_countries arguments (integer arrays). Query should check if passed array is null and if not then filter query results - for example condition below checks if target_countries are null and if not it filters addresses:

```
and (target_countries is null or a.country_id = any(target_countries))
```

The problem is that this query runs slow when for example both target_markets and target_countries are not null. To make it faster I have to write function with if..else like this (it runs twice faster):

```
create or replace function fast_companies(
  target_size int4range, 
  target_turnover int4range, 
  target_markets integer[], 
  target_countries integer[]
)
returns setof record as $$
begin
  if target_markets is not null and target_countries is not null then
    return query
    select c.id
    from companies c
    left join addresses a on c.address_id = a.id
    where
      c.company_size && target_size
      and c.turnover && target_turnover
      -- ! removed conditions checking if target_markets or target_countries are null
      and exists(select * from company_markets cm where cm.company_id = c.id and cm.market_id = any(target_markets))
      and a.country_id = any(target_countries);
  else
    -- below same query as in previous function version
    return query
    select c.id
    from companies c
    left join addresses a on c.address_id = a.id
    where
      c.company_size && target_size
      and c.turnover && target_turnover
      and (target_markets is null or exists(select * from company_markets cm where cm.company_id = c.id and cm.market_id = any(target_markets)))
      and (target_countries is null or a.country_id = any(target_countries));
  end if;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Here is query plan for slower version:

```
explain analyze
select c.id
    from companies c
    left join addresses a on c.address_id = a.id
    where
      c.company_size && '[20,)'::int4range
      and c.turnover && '[5000,)'::int4range
      and (array[717] is null or exists(select * from company_markets cm where cm.company_id = c.id and cm.market_id = any(array[717])))
      and (array[197] is null or a.country_id = any(array[197]));


"Hash Join  (cost=3271.63..48878.36 rows=1639 width=4) (actual time=55.487..67.836 rows=432 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: (c.address_id = a.id)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on companies c  (cost=469.74..45994.98 rows=5208 width=8) (actual time=14.151..25.632 rows=475 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: ((turnover && '[5000,)'::int4range) AND (company_size && '[20,)'::int4range))"
"        Filter: (alternatives: SubPlan 1 or hashed SubPlan 2)"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 10871"
"        Heap Blocks: exact=450"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on companies_tunrover_size_idx  (cost=0.00..468.43 rows=10416 width=0) (actual time=10.933..10.933 rows=11346 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: ((turnover && '[5000,)'::int4range) AND (company_size && '[20,)'::int4range))"
"        SubPlan 1"
"          ->  Index Only Scan using company_markets_pkey on company_markets cm  (cost=0.29..4.31 rows=1 width=0) (never executed)"
"                Index Cond: ((company_id = c.id) AND (market_id = ANY ('{717}'::integer[])))"
"                Heap Fetches: 0"
"        SubPlan 2"
"          ->  Index Scan using company_markets_market_id on company_markets cm_1  (cost=0.29..582.95 rows=831 width=4) (actual time=0.081..1.388 rows=757 loops=1)"
"                Index Cond: (market_id = ANY ('{717}'::integer[]))"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=2408.00..2408.00 rows=31511 width=4) (actual time=41.243..41.243 rows=31929 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1123kB"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on addresses a  (cost=592.50..2408.00 rows=31511 width=4) (actual time=7.391..26.894 rows=31929 loops=1)"
"              Recheck Cond: (country_id = ANY ('{197}'::integer[]))"
"              Heap Blocks: exact=756"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on addresses_country_id  (cost=0.00..584.62 rows=31511 width=0) (actual time=7.227..7.227 rows=31929 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (country_id = ANY ('{197}'::integer[]))"
"Planning time: 1.694 ms"
"Execution time: 76.374 ms"
```

And here is for faster version (modified two conditions to not check if target_markets and target_countries are null):

```
explain analyze
select c.id
    from companies c
    left join addresses a on c.address_id = a.id
    where
      c.company_size && '[20,)'::int4range
      and c.turnover && '[5000,)'::int4range
      and (exists(select * from company_markets cm where cm.company_id = c.id and cm.market_id = any(array[717])))
      and (a.country_id = any(array[197]));


"Nested Loop  (cost=585.61..1520.13 rows=153 width=4) (actual time=0.695..6.036 rows=432 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=585.32..1037.61 rows=487 width=8) (actual time=0.686..3.958 rows=475 loops=1)"
"        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=585.03..586.73 rows=170 width=4) (actual time=0.662..0.852 rows=757 loops=1)"
"              Group Key: cm.company_id"
"              ->  Index Scan using company_markets_market_id on company_markets cm  (cost=0.29..582.95 rows=831 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.356 rows=757 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (market_id = ANY ('{717}'::integer[]))"
"        ->  Index Scan using companies_pkey on companies c  (cost=0.29..2.64 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=757)"
"              Index Cond: (id = cm.company_id)"
"              Filter: ((company_size && '[20,)'::int4range) AND (turnover && '[5000,)'::int4range))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 0"
"  ->  Index Scan using addresses_pkey on addresses a  (cost=0.29..0.98 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=475)"
"        Index Cond: (id = c.address_id)"
"        Filter: (country_id = ANY ('{197}'::integer[]))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 0"
"Planning time: 1.012 ms"
"Execution time: 6.302 ms"
```

So is it possible to somehow "trick" postgres query planner without having to write all query variations in if..else blocks?

Comment: One issue I see with the query is that when the `target_countries` is not null, the join is converted from `left` to `inner`. Do you want that?

Comment: Also, what are the numbers with the real workload?  I don't think you are really worried about 61 milliseconds.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Well, when target_countries is not null then it should filter all records so logically it should become inner join.

Comment: @dezso Yes I do worry :). In fact this function is used internally by other queries and it causes them to be also two times slower (from ~500ms to 1s which is quite a lot).

Comment: @user606521 well, the SQL world is one where using functions for DRY is sometimes wrong.  If you rewrite the two queries (the one that call this function and the function body) into one, do you still see the slowdown?

Comment: @user606521 even the "slow" one is 76ms. For it to make a difference of 500ms you'd have to run it 7+ times. If you're running it 7+ times, perhaps you can rewrite the whole thing into one query using sets, and then optimize that (just thinking out loud)